# Gravity Forms: Dynamically add fields from JSON data

Tags: ajax, wordpress, gravityforms

What I'm trying to achieve is basically this:

1. I have a list of posts each with a checkbox next to it having the post ID as its value.
2. I also have a Gravity Form in a separate DIV on the same page having basic fields such as Name, E-mail, etc.
3. I wanted the user to be able to select multiple checkboxes and when they click a button, the post ID gets sent by AJAX to a function and the post details brought back and added to the Gravity Form. These details would also be a part of the email that gets sent when submitting the form.

I am able to get the post details by AJAX and displayed in a DIV but I am not able to find the method to add them as dynamically created fields for the Gravity Form.

Would anyone know if this is even possible and if yes, would you be able to point me to a starting point?

I looked at articles which talked about adding fields to the form using [gform_pre_render](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/) and [gfapi](https://docs.gravityforms.com/how-to-add-field-to-form-using-gfapi/) but I wasn't able to understand if this would work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does the post data need to be added to the form as separate fields or could the post details be added to the form in a single formatted field?

Comment: Each post item would be a separate field. The posts are basically a list of classes that the user can select and the classes they select will be sent to me along with the other info they fill out in the form. So each line item would include details like the class title, the timing and some other info relating to that class.